# Whitelisting a contract for single signer interaction?

Tags: safe-core

I would like to allow a safe contract to ibe able to interact with certain contracts, using just one signer EOA (not fulfilling the signing threshold). This should be possible using some module or guard right?

I understand this is a noob question but i couldn't manage ti find an answer.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to build your own module and bypass the requirement to have all owners approve a transaction.

Your module should then handle by itself validation, probably using EIP-712/EIP-1271.

To know more about building a module, you can check the docs here: https://docs.safe.global/safe-smart-account/modules

Hope it helps,
Louis